# Linq Evaluating a method as a lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am attempting to select from a List using a linq expression where the range variable is evaluated in a static method that returns boolean. I would like to select the range variable that returns true when the range variable is evaluated using the method.

```
var result = from rangeVariable in DataSource
             where (rangeVariable => Foo.MethodReturnsBoolean(rangeVariable) == true)
             select rangeVariable;
```

I get this error:

Cannot convert Lambda Expression to type 'bool' because it is not a delegate type.

Can anyone explain what is going on, and how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't need the lambda expression in the "where" clause - the query expression translation does that for you. Just use:

```
var result = from rangeVariable in DataSource
             where Foo.MethodReturnsBoolean(rangeVariable) == true
             select rangeVariable;
```

I would personally then remove the "== true" redundancy (I know this was only sample code, but...):

```
var result = from rangeVariable in DataSource
             where Foo.MethodReturnsBoolean(rangeVariable)
             select rangeVariable;
```

I'd then consider what using a query expression is actually buying you. If you're *just* doing a "where" (or just doing a "select") you may find dot notation simpler:

```
var result = DataSource.Where(x => Foo.MethodReturnsBoolean(x));
```

It gets even better though: the compiler doesn't need to infer a return value from the lambda expression (because it will always be `bool`) so you can just use a method group conversion:

```
var result = DataSource.Where(Foo.MethodReturnsBoolean);
```

How much cleaner is that? :)

Comment: When I tried var = from rangeVariable in Datacontext.table where me.MethodThatReturnsBoolean(rangeVariable) select rangeVariable I got a RUNTIME NotSupportedException: Method 'Boolean MethodThatReturnsBoolean(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL. Can any boolean function go in a where clause?  Any suggestions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662259/what-does-intellisense-mean-when-it-shows-that-it-expects-a-condition-in-the-w

Comment: @akh2103: It depends on whether you're using LINQ to Objects or LINQ to SQL etc. For LINQ to Objects, you can use any delegate you like - for a translating provider like LINQ to SQL, it has to be an expression tree that the provider knows how to convert.