# What does intellisense mean when it shows that it expects a <Condition> in the where clause of a linq query?

Tags: .net, linq

When I type a LINQ query, intellisense in Visual Studio 2010 shows that the where clause expects < condition > . As in

```
From anItem in listOfItems where ... Intellisense shows it expects a < condition >
```

What does this < condition > refer to? Is it a type? A predicate? A boolean expression? For instance, if you type...

```
listOfItems.RemoveAll(
```

...intellisense shows that it is expecting a [predicate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz.aspx). What is the analog for a < condition > in linq? (I get how to **use** a where condition, I want to know what it means). In the long run, I want to start writing complex where clauses and want to understand what LINQ is actually doing/expecting so I can understand what is going on.

I've googled around a little but nothing I find on msdn seems to fit:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms606907.aspx   (seems wrong)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7szfhaft.aspx (seems wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It pretty much just asks for a Boolean expression that can be evaluated for every `anItem` in your query expression.

The first paragraph of [where clause (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311043.aspx) sums it up nicely:

> The `where` clause is used in a query expression to specify which elements from the data source will be returned in the query expression. It applies a Boolean condition (*predicate*) to each source element (referenced by the range variable) and returns those for which the specified condition is true. A single query expression may contain multiple `where` clauses and a single clause may contain multiple predicate subexpressions.

And this is what [Where Clause (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384663.aspx) says:

> *condition*
>
> > Required. An expression that determines whether the values for the current item in the collection are included in the output collection. The expression must evaluate to a `Boolean` value or the equivalent of a `Boolean` value. If the condition evaluates to `True`, the element is included in the query result; otherwise, the element is excluded from the query result.

Comment: Thanks! But it seems to be a little more complicated. If I write a complex boolean method called myMethod and try to use it in the where clause of a linq query, I get Method myMethod has no supported translation to SQL. I think that your answer is correct (on a high-level, it wants a predicate filter) but the compiler seems to be expecting something like an expressiontree or a lambda. I'm still trying to figure this out: http://www.atrevido.net/blog/2007/09/05/Calling+Custom+Methods+In+LINQtoSQL.aspx

Answer (score 0):

"Condition" in this context means "expression that will be evaluated for each element, returns a boolean, and determines whether an element is included". Just like a SQL WHERE clause, which I have a distinct feeling they stole it from. Ahem.